# Apache sometimes not starting after reboot

Tags: apache-2.4, authentication, centos7

Sometimes, after my server (Cent OS7, default repository) reboots, Apache is not started automatically. To fix this, I reboot the server one more time, and then it works.

My Apache error logs shows the following:

```
[Mon Jun 20 00:11:34.142198 2016] [auth_digest:error] [pid 2763] (17)File exists: AH01762: Failed to create shared memory segment on file /var/logs/authdigest_shm.2763
[Mon Jun 20 00:11:34.142282 2016] [auth_digest:error] [pid 2763] (17)File exists: AH01760: failed to initialize shm - all nonce-count checking, one-time nonces, and MD5-sess algorithm disabled
[Mon Jun 20 00:11:34.142286 2016] [:emerg] [pid 2763] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
```

I'm not sure how to debug this. Any suggestion are welcome.

Comment: If the only impact is that digest authentication is disabled, then why don't you just remove mod_auth_digest?

Comment: I´ve added an extra log line (from which I conclude Apache is not started). What would be the impact of disabling mod_auth_digest?

Comment: This may be a symptom of [httpd bug 54622](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54622), where httpd leaves shared memory segments behind after exiting improperly. This is fixed in Apache [2.4.26](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.4.x/CHANGES)